# Where is Vista IIS7 "master" config file stored at?

Tags: iis-7

In IIS7 for Vista, you can select your machine and it gives you several options in which you can use to configure your system.  Where is this file stored at?  It seems like there's a big master.config file which stores all my settings like the "Connection Strings" which are inherited by the webpages.

Supposedly it's some file named machine.config but nothing I change in the IIS manager for my machine changes there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're talking about machine-wide ASP.NET configuration, look under your .NET framework config directory, e.g. `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG` - check web.config and machine.config for the settings you've been configuring.

(Note: this is a bit of an educated guess. Don't take it as definitely correct without checking. Unfortunately I can't do so myself at the moment...)

Comment: Found it, it's under web.config which is confusing from the machine.config

Comment: While your here, do you know what the point is of machine.config?  I'm guessing it goes Machine.config -> That "Master" Web.config -> Sites

Comment: machine.config is used for more than just ASP.NET. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697.aspx

Answer (score 2):

"Connection Strings" do seem to be in the [web.config file](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/how-to-encrypt-connection-string-in-webconfig/)

There can be multiple web.config files in a single web project (but not in a single directory), but here, you are referring to the [configuration system files](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/how-to-encrypt-connection-string-in-webconfig/), including:

- `windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config`: Holds the global defaults for the .NET framework settings, including some of the ASP.NET ones
- **root `web.config`**: same location, with the rest of the settings.